# Memory leakage in android app when i geve the effect on the image

Tags: android, android-camera, effects

I am new in the in camera feature. When i start the camera and after i click the image is set on the image view then i click on the effect button. now app is close .the error is memory. This app is made on below 2.2 version . when i used to run this app in 4.4 version that  time app is stooped show the memory leakeg in the app

```
12-05 17:10:53.898: E/dalvikvm-heap(21667): Out of memory on a 31961104-byte allocation.
12-05 17:10:53.938: E/dalvikvm(21667): Out of memory: Heap Size=42403KB, Allocated=34174KB, Limit=49152KB
12-05 17:10:53.938: E/dalvikvm(21667): Extra info: Footprint=42403KB, Allowed Footprint=42403KB, Trimmed=0KB
12-05 17:10:53.948: E/AndroidRuntime(21667): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-05 17:10:53.948: E/AndroidRuntime(21667): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: (Heap Size=42403KB, Allocated=34174KB)
12-05 17:10:53.948: E/AndroidRuntime(21667):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
12-05 17:10:53.948: E/AndroidRuntime(21667):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:917)
12-05 17:10:53.948: E/AndroidRuntime(21667):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:897)
12-05 17:10:53.948: E/AndroidRuntime(21667):    at com.photomarging.PhotoMargingActivity.createSepiaToningEffect(PhotoMargingActivity.java:577)
12-05 17:10:53.948: E/AndroidRuntime(21667):    at com.photomarging.PhotoMargingActivity.applyEffect(PhotoMargingActivity.java:472)
12-05 17:10:53.948: E/AndroidRuntime(21667):    at com.photomarging.PhotoMargingActivity$5.onClick(PhotoMargingActivity.java:199)
12-05 17:10:53.948: E/AndroidRuntime(21667):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3549)
12-05 17:10:53.948: E/AndroidRuntime(21667):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14393)
12-05 17:10:53.948: E/AndroidRuntime(21667):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
12-05 17:10:53.948: E/AndroidRuntime(21667):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-05 17:10:53.948: E/AndroidRuntime(21667):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
12-05 17:10:53.948: E/AndroidRuntime(21667):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
12-05 17:10:53.948: E/AndroidRuntime(21667):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-05 17:10:53.948: E/AndroidRuntime(21667):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-05 17:10:53.948: E/AndroidRuntime(21667):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-05 17:10:53.948: E/AndroidRuntime(21667):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-05 17:10:53.948: E/AndroidRuntime(21667):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

main class is here http://pastebin.com/sR5FPG22 and another class is here http://pastebin.com/GY3xzPBW (photo merging ) and i don't under stand how to solve the problem help me
and preview class is here

```
    @TargetApi(8)
  class Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private static final String TAG = "Preview";

SurfaceHolder mHolder;
public Camera camera;

Preview(Context context) {
    super(context);

    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where
    // to draw.
    if(camera==null){
    camera = Camera.open();
    }
    else{
        try {
            camera.reconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);


        camera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {

            public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera arg1) {
                FileOutputStream outStream = null;
                try {

                    ByteArrayInputStream imagestream=new     
  ByteArrayInputStream(data);
                    Bitmap     
      icon=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imagestream);

    PhotoMargingActivity.img.setImageBitmap(icon);
                    outStream = new 
       FileOutputStream(String.format("/sdcard/%d.jpg",    
  System.currentTimeMillis())); 
                    outStream.write(data);
                    outStream.close();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: 
         " + data.length);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                }
                    Preview.this.invalidate();
                    //
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
    // Because the CameraDevice object is not a shared resource, it's very
    // important to release it when the activity is paused.
    camera.stopPreview();

    camera.release();
    camera = null;
}
     ///////////////////// change in the preve class /////////////////////////////
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
    // the preview.
     //        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
      //        parameters.setPreviewSize(w, h);
      //        camera.setParameters(parameters);
      //        camera.startPreview();

    // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
    // the preview.
    //        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
     //        parameters.setPreviewSize(w, h);
     //        camera.setParameters(parameters);
      //        camera.startPreview();

     Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        List<Camera.Size> previewSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();

        // You need to choose the most appropriate previewSize for your app
        Camera.Size previewSize;//= // .... select one of previewSizes here
                 if(previewSizes.size() > 1){
                        previewSize =previewSizes.get(1);  // .... select one of    
           previewSizes here
                    }else{
                        previewSize =previewSizes.get(0);
                    }
        parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        camera.startPreview();

}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);
        Paint p= new Paint(Color.RED);
        Log.d(TAG,"draw");
        canvas.drawText("PREVIEW", canvas.getWidth()/2, canvas.getHeight()/2, p );
}
```

Comment: @ZalaJanaksinh sir this app fine working in the below 2.2 vesion but not working in above vesion

Comment: wait dear i see your code then say you

Comment: I think it`s problem of baseAdapter getview Method.it`s contain lot of memory.slove it

Comment: Please see my answer and if it is helping you then please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code in your code at certain point where you are dealing with major variables in use.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
```

Also, keep practice to recycle bitmap objects where they are not in need by following way.

```
if (bitmap != null){
  bitmap.recycle();
  bitmap = null;
}
```

Hope this helps you somehow.

Thanks.

Comment: at every point where you are using bitmap object, you should use runtime gc to clear unused memories. And like onPause or on another intent call or where bitmap object is not in use any more you can recycle your bitmap oblects. This will save your lots of memories.

Comment: try with bitmap compression before use with somewhat low quiality upto 70 or 80. This may helps you too.

Comment: @RishiGautam if my given solution helps you to solve your problem then you can accept my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @RishiGautam okay np. I will let you know if I will get something relevant to your problem.